# scheme - bad syntax after redefining the auxiliary keyword

Tags: scheme, racket

Please take a look at the following macro uses.

```
(let ()
  (define-syntax minus
    (syntax-rules (from)
      [(_ e1 from e2) (- e2 e1)]))

  ; a  
  (minus 1 from 2)
  ;; => 1

  ; b
  (define from 3)
  (minus from from 2) 
  ;; => -1

  ; c
  (minus 1 from 2)
  ;; => 1

  ; d
  #; 
  (let ([from 1])
    (minus 1 from 2))
  ;; bad syntax
  )
```

I have noticed something unexpected with the auxiliary syntax `from` involved in the `minus` macro.

It seems to me `from` can be redefined wherever we want. However look like case `d` will not work.

This can be easily reproduced with `Racket`.

Any idea why there is a bad syntax?

Thanks,

---

**Edit:**

Note if I modify the definition a little, it will be valid again.

```
(let ()
  (define-syntax minus
    (syntax-rules (from)
      [(_ e1 from e2) (- e2 e1)]
      [(_ e1 e2 _) (- e2 e1)]))

  ; a
  (minus 1 from 2)
  ;; => 1

  ; b
  (let ([from 1])
    (minus 1 from 2))
  ;; => 0
  )
```

Since `free-identifier=?` is used for the implicit guard for the auxiliary keywords, the `from` in case `b` is not treated as a keyword, then the first case will not be matched.

Comment: Also this behavior is mentioned in the r6rs section 11.19.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/stx-patterns.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fstxcase-scheme..rkt%29._syntax-rules%29%29) suggests, `syntax-rules` expands to `syntax-case`. And indeed, `syntax-case` has the same problem:

```
#lang racket

(define-syntax (minus stx)
  (syntax-case stx (from)
    [(_ e1 from e2) #'(- e2 e1)]))

(let ([from 1])
  (minus 1 from 2))
;; => minus: bad syntax in: (minus 1 from 2)
```

However, there's a variant of `syntax-case` named [`syntax-case*`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/stx-patterns.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fstxcase-scheme..rkt%29._syntax-case%2A%29%29). Its documentation states that:

> Like syntax-case, but id-compare-expr must produce a procedure that accepts two arguments. A literal-id in a pattern matches an identifier for which the procedure returns true when given the identifier to match (as the first argument) and the identifier in the pattern (as the second argument).
>
> In other words, syntax-case is like syntax-case* with an id-compare-expr that produces free-identifier=?.

So we can try this:

```
#lang racket

(define-for-syntax (my-comparator a b)
  (println a)
  (println b)
  (println (free-identifier=? a b))
  (free-identifier=? a b))

(define-syntax (minus stx)
  (syntax-case* stx (from) my-comparator
    [(_ e1 from e2) #'(- e2 e1)]))

(minus 1 from 2)
;; => .#<syntax:unsaved-editor:13:9 from>
;; => .#<syntax:unsaved-editor:11:11 from>
;; => #t

(let ([from 1])
  (minus 1 from 2))

;; => .#<syntax:unsaved-editor:19:11 from>
;; => .#<syntax:unsaved-editor:11:11 from>
;; => #f
;; => minus: bad syntax in: (minus 1 from 2)
```

As you can see, the problem is that [`free-identifier=?`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/stxcmp.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._free-identifier~3d~3f%29%29) finds that both `from` are not equal in the latter case.

So, to make this work, simply supply your own comparator that doesn't use `free-identifier=?`:

```
#lang racket

(define-for-syntax (my-comparator a b)
  (eq? (syntax->datum a) (syntax->datum b)))

(define-syntax (minus stx)
  (syntax-case* stx (from) my-comparator
    [(_ e1 from e2) #'(- e2 e1)]))

(minus 1 from 2)
;; => 1

(let ([from 1])
  (minus 1 from 2))
;; => 1
```

---

If somehow you can't use `syntax-case*`, you can also do this:

```
(define-syntax (minus stx)
  (syntax-case stx () 
    [(_ e1 from e2)
     (eq? (syntax->datum #'from) 'from) ; a guard
     #'(- e2 e1)]))
```

though it gets tedious when you have several literal ids.

Comment: I see. I think the tricky part is that under `symbolic-identifier=?` the auxiliary keyword is definitely a keyword, but under `free-identifier=?` it can actually be either a variable (if bound) or a keyword (if free).